# Unable to connect to AWS DocumentDB got "A timeout occured after 30000ms"

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am running a C# script to perform insert operations to a cluster. Whenever I try to perform a insert operation to the database, I get an error starting with.
The cluster is a part of AWS DocumentDB.

***A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector***

`System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "2", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 2, EndPoint : "Unspecified/xyz:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/xyz:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.`

```
        public void connection()
        {
            string template = "mongodb://{0}:{1}@{2}/admin?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference={3}&retryWrites=false";
            string username = "unknown";
            string password = "unknown";
            string readPreference = "secondaryPreferred";
            string clusterEndpoint = "unknown";
            string connectionString = String.Format(template, username, password, clusterEndpoint, readPreference);

            string pathToCAFile = @"E:\path\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem";

            X509Store localTrustStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificateCollection.Import(pathToCAFile);
            try
            {
                localTrustStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                localTrustStore.AddRange(certificateCollection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Root certificate import failed: " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                localTrustStore.Close();
            }

            var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
            var client = new MongoClient(settings);

            var database = client.GetDatabase("admin");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("samplecollection");
            var docToInsert = new BsonDocument { { "pi", 3.14159 } };
            collection.InsertOne(docToInsert);
        }
```

Hiding the credentials as it is confidential. But please help me know how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Try to check the persmission

Comment: try set `tls=true` to connectionString

Comment: Hi. We need more details. Are you able to connect with mongo shell? DocumentDB is a VPC only service, are you running the script from the same VPC? The security group attached to the DocumentDB cluster is configured correctly? It looks that you have TLS disabled in the script, but DocumentDB requires TLS connections by default (can be disabled by disabling TLS in the parameter group).